# query_posts based on a meta_key

Tags: wp-query, order

I have custom post type of `brand` and custom field generated via types plugin, `wpcf-sorter` trying to manually create a field to sort my posts. Some of the posts have this custom field populated with a numeric value and others don't have it at all since we're developing this mid-way.

My code is:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'brand',
  'posts_per_page' => 999,
  'meta_key'       => 'wpcf-sorter',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'          => 'DESC'
);
```

This will pull out all the posts that **have** the `wpcf-sorter` meta key. Is there a way to pull every post and if it has the `wpcf-sorter`, show them first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219031/80532) is pretty covering for this I think:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'brand',
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'meta_query'  => array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
           'key'     => 'wpcf-sorter',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
          'key'     => 'wpcf-sorter',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS',
       ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
);
```

That should give you all posts with `wpcf-sorter`-value set first, then the rest, both sets ordered by date.

Comment: Thank you very much, Emil. This is the final version that sorts correctly. 
`code` $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'brand',
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
        'meta_query'  => array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key'     => 'wpcf-sorter',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
              'key'     => 'wpcf-sorter',
              'compare' => 'EXISTS',
           ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC'),
    ); `code`

Comment: Much appreciated!