# Order by two meta keys

Tags: wp-query, functions, meta-query

I have this code which works fine:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'brands',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'br_type',
            'value' => 'Aviation'
    )),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'br_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```

However, I need to order first by ascending order by another custom field `"br_category"` and then by the name `br_name`. I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I found my answer here! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126928/15209

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% certain what specific order you're asking for, but you just need to assign an associative array to the 'orderby' value.  Here's an example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'brands',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'br_type',
            'value' => 'Aviation'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'br_category'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'br_name'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => [
        'br_category' => 'ASC',
        'br_name' => 'ASC',
        'br_type' => 'ASC'
    ],
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```

Comment: You can check this answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246358/125227
although the question is closed but you get the idea for order by multiple meta keys.