# Order by nested named meta queries with 'exists' and 'not exists'

Tags: meta-query, order

Each of my posts (online store items) has meta keys:

1. `tdlrm_mp` - my own menu_position (goes from 1 up and, unlike the wp_posts menu_position, may not exist)
2. `1C_quantity_total` - number of items in stock

I'd like the items to be output in the following order:

1. first, the ones where `tdlrm_mp` exists, ordered by `tdlrm_mp` lowest to highest
2. then, the ones where `tdlrm_mp` does not exist, ordered by `1C_quantity_total`, highest to lowest

Here are the arguments for my meta query:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
                'tdlrm_mp_key' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    'tdlrm_mp_exists' => array(
                        'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    'tdlrm_mp_not_exists' => array(
                        'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    )
                ),
                'quantity_total' => array(
                    'key'     => '1C_quantity_total',
                    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
            );
            $args['orderby'] = array(
                'tdlrm_mp_key' => 'ASC',
                'quantity_total' => 'DESC'
            );
```

This doesn't seem to work, the posts get ordered by quantity only. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried plain

```
$args['orderby'] = array(
   'tdlrm_mp' => 'ASC',
   '1C_quantity_total' => 'DESC',
);
```

But it first outputs the items where `tdlrm_mp` does not exist

I've also found this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126772/query-to-sort-a-list-by-meta-key-first-if-it-exists-and-show-remaining-posts) , but can't figure out if it applies here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the key in your `orderby` array needs to reference an array in `meta_query` which contains a direct `key` item, e.g. `'key' => 'tdlrm_mp'`. So for example, you should have used `'tdlrm_mp_exists' => 'ASC',` and not `'tdlrm_mp_key' => 'ASC'` in your `$args['orderby']`.

However, that wouldn't actually sort the posts in the way you wanted it to, but I was simply showing you the correct syntax that one should use.

But don't fret, what you're trying to do is possible :)

### And here's how:

1. Set the `meta_query` to:

   ```php
   $args['meta_query'] = array(
       array(
           'relation'     => 'OR',
           // select posts that have the tdlrm_mp meta
           'has_tdlrm_mp' => array(
               'key'  => 'tdlrm_mp',
               'type' => 'NUMERIC',
           ),
           // select posts that don't have the meta
           'no_tdlrm_mp'  => array(
               'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
           ),
       ),
       array(
           'relation'              => 'OR',
           // select posts that have the 1C_quantity_total meta
           'has_1C_quantity_total' => array(
               'key'  => '1C_quantity_total',
               'type' => 'NUMERIC',
           ),
           // select posts that don't have the meta
           'no_1C_quantity_total'  => array(
               'key'     => '1C_quantity_total',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
           ),
       ),
   );
   ```
2. Set the `orderby` to `none` because we'll use a completely custom one.
3. **Before** you run `new WP_Query()`, use the [`posts_orderby` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) to modify the `ORDER BY` clause and basically we use the [`CASE` *operator*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) to achieve the (pretty complex) sorting you wanted:

   ```php
   $_filter = true; // enable the filter below
   add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, $query ) use ( &$_filter ) {
       if ( $_filter ) {
           global $wpdb;

           $meta_clauses          = $query->meta_query->get_clauses();
           $has_tdlrm_mp          = $meta_clauses['has_tdlrm_mp']['alias'];
           $has_1C_quantity_total = $meta_clauses['has_1C_quantity_total']['alias'];

           // 1st, sort by the meta key, and posts without the meta are placed at
           // the bottom (or 3rd position).
           $orderby = "
   CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
       WHEN 'tdlrm_mp'          THEN 1
       WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN 2
       ELSE 3
   END ASC";

           // 2nd, sort by the meta value, only for the posts in position 1 and 2
           // above.
           $orderby .= ",
   CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
       WHEN 'tdlrm_mp'          THEN {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_value+0
   END ASC,
   CASE {$has_1C_quantity_total}.meta_key
       WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN {$has_1C_quantity_total}.meta_value+0
   END DESC";

           // 3rd, now optionally sort the posts in the 3rd position above. Here,
           // we sort them by the post date.
           $orderby .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC";
       }

       return $orderby;
   }, 10, 2 );

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   $_filter = false; // disable the filter above
   ```

## Update

Sorry, I revised my answer several times and yet, I actually still forgot to correct the table alias  (in step 3 above).

Now I've corrected it, and in addition, I also used [`WP_Meta_Query::get_clauses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/get_clauses/) instead of hard-coding the (table) alias. Many thanks to [@Artem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/190417/artem) and his [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392642/whats-wrong-with-this-wp-query)!

Comment: PS: If you wanted to include posts that **do not have** *both* the `tdlrm_mp` and `1C_quantity_total` meta, then yes, nested meta queries are needed. And if so, let me know.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you Sally.
Yes, I wanted to include posts that don't have both. That's why I used a nested query with "EXISTS" and "NOT EXISTS".

Comment: hm, meta_value+0 is interesting.

Comment: And $orderby = "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key DESC"; - it orders meta keys alphabetically, so if the names were different, I might have had to use 'ASC', right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And as for the `meta_value+0`, that's a simple way to cast the meta value as a number, but you could also use the `CAST` function, e.g. `CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED)`. Anyway, I'll revise my answer soon.

Comment: I've revised my answer (and btw, sorry about the "parse_orderby"..). Let me know.

Comment: Somehow, it doesn't work, see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392642/whats-wrong-with-this-wp-query). If I write a mysql query with the orderby part you wrote, it works, though.

Comment: Thank you for the update Sally, I did replace $query->query_vars with $query->query.

Comment: I already removed that update (and deleted my answer to the linked question) because `$query->query_vars` actually does work. It's just that I was being confused. 

Comment: I've revised my answer (basically I reverted back to [revision 5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/392525/5) and then corrected the table alias in the `ORDER BY` clause). Many sorry for the hassles! And *hopefully this time I made no more silly mistakes*... (also, I deleted my previous comment)

Comment: Oh well, your 'silly mistakes' are 'WP wizardry' to me ) I love to learn, and so far, this has been a great opportunity to dive deeper into the inner workings of WordPress. Hopefully, this will help someone else, too. I will now go through your revised answer and test our solutions, and let you know the results.

Comment: Also, to whoever may need this in the future. Later I am going to expand this solution to allow different post orders for different categories, like `tdlrm_mp_514`, `tdlrm_mp_515`. On the post edit page there will be dropdowns, one for each assigned term. The dropdowns will show as many options as there are ordered items in the category, plus one. If a user chooses an existing order position, the other posts will be reordered accordingly. That's the plan. If it hadn't been, it would be wiser to go with wp_posts.menu_order.