# Sort by presence of thumbnail

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Looking to `ORDER BY` the result of [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) based on presence of post thumbnail.

```
  $query_args = [
    'post_type'     => 'custom_project',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => 20,
    'orderby'   => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'value' => "whatever",
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'paged' => false,
    'orderby' => 'title'
  ];
```

Producing:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN \
wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN \
wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key \
= '_thumbnail_id' ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
  OR 
  mt1.post_id IS NULL
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'custom_project' \
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY \
wp_posts.post_title DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

If I add `'meta_key'  => '_thumbnail_id'`, this only returns posts that contain a featured image. Otherwise, no sorting. I have unsuccessfully tried variations with with `compare` values and including `'_thumbnail_id'` in a second tax query array and am considering just using `array_sort` after the fact, but hoping for a more elegant solution.

Have tried two different solutions from [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219031/48604), but unsuccessful using `wp 5.8.1`.

##### Desired Result:

1. I have a thumbnail
2. I have a thumbnail
3. I have a thumbnail
4. I have a thumbnail
5. I don't have a thumbnail
6. I don't have a thumbnail

Comment: Based on what exactly do they have to be sorted? the thumbnail file name? like `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and so on?

Comment: Wanting the ones _with_ thumbnails to be at the end of the result. Secondary sorting can be by title.

Comment: at the end of all the results or results with alphabetical order? like, we want to see a list of the posts we have, at for example, the last 20 items on the list are the ones without a thumbnail? OR, we want all of the posts displayed sorted out with the titles and if two posts have the same title, we want the one without the the thumbnail to be shown after the one that has one? If you provide me with an example of what data you have and how you want it to look, I can help with the code.

Comment: Fantastic. I want the first example, where the last 20 items are the ones without a thumbnail. Will update post...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as suggested: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/370841/48604

Comment: No worries, I got you. writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, and it is basically a combination of the two answers [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126928/48604) and then following the tip to remove the `meta_key` key following WP Version 4.1 [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219031/48604) (same post):

```
  $query_args = [
    'post_type'     => 'custom',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'   => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC' ),
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        )
    ),
    'paged' => false,
  ];
```

I guess if one needed to support older versions WP you would have to add that key dynamically.

Also of note, I had, at one point in hacking, decreased `posts_per_page` to a number at which I wasn't returning both the posts *with* and *without* the featured image, so spent some time head scratching why it still "wasn't working".

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy!

```
$args_for_query1 = [
    'post_type'     => 'custom_project',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        ) 
    )
];
  
$args_for_query2 = [
    'post_type'     => 'custom_project',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_key'  => '_thumbnail_id',
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
];

$query1 = new WP_Query($args_for_query1);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args_for_query2);

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
$wp_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;
```

Comment: Interesting! Are we querying the DB once or three times in this code?

Comment: Twice actually.

Comment: Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but can't it be done with a single query? I think that perhaps just running the query once (without the orderby and meta_key) and running it through array_sort.

Comment: Just noticed something. I was trying, above, to put my `meta_query` in with the `tax_query`!

Comment: updated my post accordingly.

Comment: you can do that, but I don't think it would make things amazingly better. any specific reason?

Comment: My understanding is that fewer trips to the database is better, when possible. From a practical standpoint, don't know how much difference it would make, but in this case, the items are returned by a shortcode which could be run multiple times on a page, which might make the diff between 20 and 40 queries.

Comment: You do have have a point. My knowledge on the subject isn't sufficient. I'm excited to know about a better way.